# QR code implementation

Tags: qr-code

I have requirement related to QR code, My friend owns a food shop (aka merchant), i need to implement a QR code for his customers, since i am new to this QR code thing i need some help where should i start researching on this, So the scenario is
1) A customer sees a brochure with a list of food items in his (customer) home
2) the customer using his mobile he scans the food item he likes, now the merchant should receive the customer details (address/phone) automatically after the scan.

So now the question from where i need to start to research on this

Basically as far i know first the customer data has to be there with the merchant (this has to be done by customer), so then when he scans, the ordered item along with his details has to be sent to the mechant.

SO where can i start researching on this to implement this, what technologies i need to know?

Any book/tutorial is there on this?

Comment: Before even tackling the QR thing (which is quite easy as bazillions of readymade solutions exist) it seems that you first have to tackle some process issues.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?, yeah i saw a ready made solutions (like netwaiter) but it comes with monthly charges, but i want to provide onetime solution and the money would be spent for our own development charges onetime only, so any other solutions where should i start?

Comment: if this would be implemented in our place we would be the first people to implement in our state in india, so appreciate any one's solution from where i need to start on this???

Comment: getting the qr codes is the easy part - either use a ready to use library or even have the qr's generated by some online service - but you will need to write a mobile phone app for each supported mobile phone type, ie at least android and ios

Comment: Even with your updates I think your question is way, way to broad. The "where do I start" questions are not suited for Stackoverflow, we give specific answers/solutions to specific questions/problems.

Answer (score 1):

One JavaScript implementation is available from the ShieldUI open source library, available here:
https://github.com/shieldui/shieldui-lite
One example of a jquery plugin implementation is available here:
http://demos.shieldui.com/web/qrcode/api

Answer (score 0):

Don't implement anything. Use the zxing library for encoding and decoding: http://code.Google.com/p/zxing

You haven't really said what your technical needs are though. And you seem to need to nail down product requirements before you think too hard about implementation.

Comment: The product requirement is very simple, 1) i need to implement the QR code for the list of products 2) Send the customer information when the customer scans the product to the merchant along with the product details which he had scanned... Thats it, the thing i am not sure where to start, should i get the data from the customers first? and save it in a database? or is there any readmade solution where i can implement part of my development (like any php apis), since for me first QR code itself is new to me so i have some difficulties to understand the whole thing...